# Enable http bookmarklet in ssl site?

Tags: javascript, https, bookmarklet

I have a bookmarklet running on a non-ssl site (http) and this does not open on a ssl enabled site. What is the best tweak to enable opening bookmarks in https sites?

Comment: What browser are you using.. IE lets you set mixed zone... in the last few version of chome they do not allow non-ssl script run on a ssl page.. i downgraded to chrome 19.. and it will prompt you to allow the non-ssl script to run.. if you do downgrade chrome you will have to disable auto updates because chrome likes to upgraded you without know it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to make the site hosting the bookmarklet https so that it works in both http and https sites.

Comment: as well as that, if your bookmarklet references an absolute url, you should use a protocol relative url, such as `//example.com/example.json` instead of `http://example.com/example.json`